# Send data from django to html

Tags: python, html, django

I want to get data from database and send that to html page using django-python.

What I'm doing in python file is

```
def module1(request):
    table_list=student.objects.all()
    context={'table_list' : table_list}    
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

And in html is

```
<div class="rightbox">
            In right box. data is :<br> <br>              
       {% if table_list %} 
        <ul> {% for item in table_list %} 
              <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
              <li>{{ item.address }}</li>
              <li>{{ item.mob_no }}</li>

              {% endfor %} 
        </ul> 
       {% else %} 
            <p>somethings is wrong</p> 
        {% endif %}

        </div>
```

Nothing is being sent to html file. It is constantly going in else block. 
I don't know where I'm making mistake.Please help me.

Comment: What does `print(table_list)` from that view function show?

Comment: It is not working it. I'm using django 1.9.9

Comment: It shows error as :
  Could not parse the remainder: '(table_list)' from 'print(table_list)'

Comment: @AmeyaJoshi can you add the print to the "module1(request)" before the return statement? print table_list

Comment: @Lin ,let me check it.. I'm new to django so..

Comment: Can you post the code for your student model ?

Comment: I´m not seeing the problem now. It looks like a stupid thing. By the way, How is your urls.py? And you calling your controller properly? You can try another approach instead: return render_to_response('index.html', {'table_list' : table_list},
context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as we don't see your `student` model (which should be in your `models.py` and be imported in your `vievs.py`) and your code doesn't throw any exceptions it seems that your `table_list` is empty. To iterate it in more convenient way you can use built in `for ... empty` template tag:

```
<div class="rightbox">
    In right box. data is :<br> <br>              
    <ul>
    {% for item in table_list %} 
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ item.address }}</li>
        <li>{{ item.mob_no }}</li>
    {% empty %} 
        <p>somethings is wrong</p>
    {% endfor %} 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Try this and see what happens. If you'll find yourself in `{% empty %}` block - your `table_list` is empty which is points to empty table in database.

Also check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) for this tag.